# PHP auto notification via email, the logic behind this

Tags: php, email, notifications, logic

For example, I want my client to be notify via email on a set date and time in the future. Can PHP do this even if nobody is visiting the website?

What condition should I make? Should I save this on session, etc... I just want to know the logic on this. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is using Linux, then you can use `cron jobs`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cron job. And maybe its not the answer to your question but facebook uses this system too. Very interesting info about facebook's opensource platform https://developers.facebook.com/opensource/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use a cron (or equivalent) job with PHP. A cron job executes a page every x time.